# Use vsixsigntool.exe with SafeNet HSM | sign VSIX using HSM

Tags: digital-signature, vsix, code-signing-certificate, hardware-security-module

Earlier I successfully used [vsixsigntool.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/signing-vsix-packages) to sign extensions for Visual Studio in the VSIX format. The command line call looked like this:

```
vsixsigntool.exe sign /f %PFX% /p %PWD% /sha1 %HASH% /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 /td sha256 <path_to_vsix>
```

, where %PFX% is the path to the PFX file with my code signing certificate (CSS), %PWD% is its password, and %HASH% is an SHA1 hash of my CSS.

But this time my CSS supplier, GlobalSign, allowed me to generate and store the new CSS only on a SafeNet 5110 USB token because of global change in security policy related to CSSs. As such, I no longer have a PFX file and can't use vsixsigntool as earlier because of this.

Is there a way to use vsixsigntool with the CSS stored on a SafeNet hardware security module?

Perhaps, there are also alternative solutions allowing us to sign VSIXs using a CSS stored on an HSM. They can be also an answer to my question.

Comment: See my article "Code signing a VSIX package with a hardware-based USB token key": https://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2023/09/20/code-signing-a-vsix-package-with-a-hardware-based-usb-token-key/

Comment: @CarlosQuintero, why don't publish it as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don’t have a password-protected .pfx file with the certificate and the private key, you can’t use the /p flag (for the password) of the vsixsigntool.exe tool. Instead, you must provide access to the private key inside the USB device using the following flags:

- /f: Path to the certificate file in .p7b format (without the private key)
- /csp : Specify the Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) containing the Key Container of the private key.
- /k : Specify the nameof the Key Container of the private key.

You have the details in my article:

Code signing a VSIX package with a hardware-based USB token key:

https://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2023/09/20/code-signing-a-vsix-package-with-a-hardware-based-usb-token-key/

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work for me. I used this command: `VSIXSignTool.exe sign /f <path_to_p7b> /csp "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0" <CertificateKeyContainerName> /sha1 <CertificateSHA1Thumbprint> /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 /fd sha256 <path_to_vsix>`. Got the following error from vsicsigntool: "Could not sign package <path_to_vsix>: Error Code - 8009000d." What it could be? I can't find this error code in the Internet.

Comment: 8009000D is error "NTE_NO_KEY".

When you insert the hardware-based USB, the smart card driver should create a certificate in the Windows Certificate Store for users (certmgr), node Personal > Certificates. It is there?

In fact I think (not tested) that maybe the /f flag for the p7b file on disk is not necessary since the certificate (without the private key) is loaded on Windows, with the private key in the inserted USB device. I think to remember that if you remove the USB device, when trying to use the certificate of the store, Windows asks you to insert the device.

Comment: I got the SHA thumbprint for my CSS from certmgr.msc, so the certificate is there. It seems I exported my previous expired certificate yesterday. I exported the correct one today, but now I get Error Code 80092004. VSIXSigntool does not work without /f - tells this file (key) is mandatory.

Comment: 0x80092004 is CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Sorry, but this does not help me anyhow.

Comment: Which Windows version do you have? I have the same issue under Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I don't know the cause of 0x80092004 is CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND but I have opened several tickets to Microsoft to improve the experiencing of code signing extensions with hardware devices because currently it is extremely tricky (please vote for them):

Comment: 1) Misleading documentation regarding SHA256 required to sign VSIX packages: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Misleading-documentation-regarding-SHA25/10481764

Comment: 2) Insufficient documentation to sign VSIX packages: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Insufficient-documentation-to-sign-VSIX/10481776

Comment: 3) Add support in Visual Studio 2015 and higher for ECDSA-SHA256 (and not only RSA-SHA256) for code-signing VSIX packages: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-support-in-Visual-Studio-2015-and-hi/10481797

Comment: 4) VSIXInstaller should log the exception that causes "Invalid signature" installing code-signed VSIX extensions: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VSIXInstaller-should-log-the-exception-t/10481800

Comment: 5) vsixsigntool.exe shows incorrect error message when duplicating the /fd flag: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vsixsigntoolexe-shows-incorrect-error-m/10481804

Comment: And I have still to investigate an issue with the /csp parameter with the new certificate that I got from ssl.com for my Yubikey. I will update my article once I get new data. Please note that if you key is ECC and not RSA, even if you solve your problem and get your VSIX package signed, it won't work with VSIXInstaller ("Invalid signature" warning) due to the issue of the problem #3 (lack of support for ECDSA-SHA256 in VS extensions) so you can save your time (I wasted my weekend of this...)